# Where are the factory_girl records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, integration-testing, factory-bot

I'm trying to perform an integration test via **Watir** and **RSpec**. So, I created a test file within /integration and wrote a test, which adds a test user into a base via **factory_girl**.

The problem is — I can't actually perform a login with my test user. The test I wrote looks as following:

```
...

before(:each)
  @user = Factory(:user)
  @browser = FireWatir::Firefox.new
end

it "should login"
  @browser.text_field(:id, "username").set(@user.username)
  @browser.text_field(:id, "password").set(@user.password)
  @browser.button(:id, "get_in").click
end

...
```

As I'm starting the test and see a "performance" in browser, it always fires up a `Username is not valid` error.

I've started an investigation, and did a small trick. First of all I've started to have doubts if the factory actually creates the user in DB. So after the immediate call to factory I've put some `puts User.find` stuff only to discover that the user **is** actually in DB. Ok, but as user still couldn't have logged in I've decided to see if he's present in DB with my own eyes.

I've added a `sleep` right after a factory call, and went to see what's in the DB at the moment. I was crushed to see that the user is actually missing there! How come? Still, when I'm trying to output a user within the code, he is actually being fetched from somewhere. **So where does the records, made by factory_girl within a runtime lie?** Is it `test` or `dev` DB? I don't get it.

I've 10 times checked if I'm running my Mongrel in `test` mode (does it matter? I think it does, as I'm trying to tun an integration test) and if my `database.yml` holds the correct connection specific data.

I'm using an **authlogic**, if that can give any clue (no, putting `activate_authlogic` doesn't work here).

Comment: Your user generate by Factory girl is activated or something like that ?

Comment: @shingara at the very moment I call the Factory, constructor `User` is being built and applied to db.

Comment: Yes, but during the connection by your controller, it can check if your is activate it or not by email by example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the solution went strange — I put factories to before(:all) block, and all the stuff worked as it should.

Comment: See jbpros answer - it's because of transactions in tests, and the fact that different DB connections can't look into each other's transactions. before(:all) is outside of the transactions around each test.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget that RSpec is probably using transations when running the specs. RSpec will wrap the execution of the spec within a transaction and rollback at the end. It means you won't be able to see the record from outside that transaction (i.e. from another SQL connection).

If you want to ensure the user record is actually created by Factory Girl, you can do something like:

```
before(:each)
  @user = Factory(:user)
  User.find_by_username(@user.username).should_not be_nil
  @browser = FireWatir::Firefox.new
end
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, solved a two hour search to get my JS tests working.

Answer (score -1):

Factory Girl is going to create temporary DB entries in your test database.  Your tests database is going to be cleared out after each test.